# At a fixed inital velocity, What throwing angle will give the projectile the most trajectory length?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

This is a diagram of a projectile motion:

[image: projectile motion]
Given a constant initial velocity, What angle gives the most trajectory length?

By length I mean the length of the parabola from the point the ball is shot to the point it reaches $y=0$ again.

I fist thought that more time of travel gives more trajectory length so 90 degrees but is wasn't so.
at about 80 degrees the trajectory length was more.

My other idea was that more range gives more length so angle should be 45 degree. but again the length at 80 degree was more.

So I deducted the angle should be between 45 and 80, but I had no idea how to calculate the perimeter of a parabolic section.

Comment: A dangerously tempting question to play with over the Christmas period, but I don't see that there is any physics in it. It's just [calculating an arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length), which is a routine mathematical operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=ut\sin \alpha  - \frac{gt^2}{2}$$

$$x=ut \cos \alpha$$

Trajectory Length $s$

$$s = \int_0^T \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2} dt$$

$\dot{x}=u\cos{\alpha}$

$\dot{y}=u\sin\alpha-gt$

$T=\frac{2u\sin \alpha}{g}$

So,

$$s = \int_0^T \sqrt{u^2\cos^2 \alpha+(u\sin \alpha-gt)^2} dt$$

This is of the form 
$I=\int \sqrt{a^2+z^2} dz=\frac{1}{2}\bigg[z\sqrt{z^2+a^2}+a^2\ln\bigg[z+\sqrt{z^2+a^2}\bigg]\bigg]$

here

$a=u\cos \alpha$ and $z=u\sin \alpha -gt$

assume $u=g=1$

$$s=\sin \alpha - \frac{1}{2}\cos^2 \alpha \ln\bigg [\frac{1-\sin \alpha}{1+ \sin \alpha}\bigg ]$$

We have to solve for $\frac{ds}{d \alpha}=0$

But things get messy and $\alpha$ cannot be separated in a simple way, So I wrote a code and iterated $\alpha $ over $0^\circ$ to $89^\circ$, And found the Max value of $s$ to be at approximately $\alpha=57 ^\circ$

Online resources give $\alpha=56.5 ^\circ$, So yes, this is close enough